# RealityKit – arView.scene add AnchorEntity

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

Apple Document: [Stored Entities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/stored_entities)

My another question: [RealityKit – Stored Entities & Load the Scene Aynchronously from the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497198/realitykit-stored-entities-load-the-scene-aynchronously-from-the-url)

My function result return a (Entity & HasAnchoring)

My question is...How to show the AnchorEntity.(self.arView.scene.addAnchor??)

I'm new here.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After you have loaded the AnchorEntity you can add it to the scene like this:

```
arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
```

And that should be it. For instance if you set horizontal plane anchoring when you created the project in RealityComposer, then it should place your AnchorEntity once you detect a horizontal plane

There is a bug in iOS 13.5 to 13.6.1. It is fixed in the iOS 14 beta. A workaround is to use the .rcproject file format instead.

```
if let anchor = try? Entity.loadAnchor(named: "AR") {            
    arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you so late.I am looking for a job.  It's crash when I used the code.anchor is (Entity & HasAnchoring). [Here is my code](https://github.com/HincaTseng/TestLoadScene) Can you give me some tips? THX.Have a good day.

Comment: There is a bug in iOS 13.5 to 13.6.1 which makes loading AnchorEntities crash like it does in your code. There is not much you can do about this, but it seems to have been fixed in the iOS 14 beta. So either you can update to the beta or you could use the .rcproject file format as a workaround instead. I'll update my answer with the workaround

Comment: Thank you very very very much. 